# asp.net membership api - login control (where is the code executing?)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

here is the login page that created for you when you create a default application in asp.net and i am trying to understand where does the actually code validating/authenticating the userid and password?, i did not find any code-behind code except this: where does it validating the username and password?

i see the `CommandName="Login"` but dont find the code....

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
        }
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Log In
    </h2>
    <p>
        Please enter your username and password.
        <asp:HyperLink ID="RegisterHyperLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">Register</asp:HyperLink> if you don't have an account.
    </p>
    <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <span class="failureNotification">
                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </span>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
                 ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            <div class="accountInfo">
                <fieldset class="login">
                    <legend>Account Information</legend>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                             CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                        <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
                <p class="submitButton">
                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
                </p>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implement is in the `Login.OnBubbleEvent` method. For more information, refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.onbubbleevent.aspx

Comment: You can use some third party tools, such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture the communication. On the other hand, you may try to debug it in the .net framework source code. See the method in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Comment: wow... so what if; if i have to add the logic before/after the user being authenticated?

Comment: `Login.OnLoggingIn` raises the LoggingIn event when a user submits login information but before the authentication takes place. `Login.OnLoggedIn` raises the LoggedIn event after the user logs in to the Web site and has been authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Login.OnBubbleEvent as Edward Zhu pointed out is the correct answer. To further the understanding what happens here is the code snippet from System.Web.dll for the event (using Reflector.exe)

```
protected override bool OnBubbleEvent(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    bool flag = false;
    if (e is CommandEventArgs)
    {
        CommandEventArgs args = (CommandEventArgs) e;
        if (string.Equals(args.CommandName, LoginButtonCommandName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            this.AttemptLogin();
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

LoginButtonCommandName defaults to "Login"

Pawel

Answer (score 0):

Search in your code for a class that inherits : MembershipProvider

I have this class

```
public class TsMembershiProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private Dictionary<string, MembershipUser> _Users;

    // MembershipProvider Properties
    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordReset
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
    {
        get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
    {
        get { return 2; }
    }

    public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
    {
        get { return 5; }
    }

    public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
    {
        get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
    {
        get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
    {
        get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
    {
        get { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    // MembershipProvider Methods
    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        // Verify that config isn't null
        if (config == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("config");

        // Assign the provider a default name if it doesn't have one
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            name = "TsMembershipProvider";

        // Add a default "description" attribute to config if the
        // attribute doesn't exist or is empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["description"]))
        {

            config.Add("description", "Membership provider");
        }

        // Call the base class's Initialize method
        base.Initialize(name, config);

        // Throw an exception if unrecognized attributes remain
        if (config.Count > 0)
        {
            string attr = config.GetKey(0);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(attr))
                throw new ProviderException
                    ("Unrecognized attribute: " + attr);
        }
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            return false;

        SqlDataReader dr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(SqlHelper.ConnString, "spc_UserAuthorization", username, password);

        bool ret = dr.HasRows;

        return ret;
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        // Note: This implementation ignores userIsOnline

        // Validate input parameters
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            return null;

        // Retrieve the user from the database

        MembershipUser user = MU(username, userIsOnline); //userIsOnline = AltEmail - gets alternative email (hvb)
        return user;
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex,
        int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        // Note: This implementation ignores pageIndex and pageSize,
        // and it doesn't sort the MembershipUser objects returned

        // Make sure the data source has been loaded
        ReadMembershipDataStore();

        MembershipUserCollection users =
            new MembershipUserCollection();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MembershipUser> pair in _Users)
            users.Add(pair.Value);

        totalRecords = users.Count;
        return users;
    }

    public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(username);
        if (u == null || oldPassword != u.GetPassword())
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (newPassword.Length < MinRequiredPasswordLength)
        {
            return false;
        }

        CharEnumerator chars = newPassword.GetEnumerator();
        int nr = 0;
        while (chars.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!Char.IsLetterOrDigit(chars.Current))
                nr++;
        }

        if (MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters < nr)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // CALL TO SQL TO CHANGE PASSWORD
        return true;
    }

    public override bool
        ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username,
        string password, string newPasswordQuestion,
        string newPasswordAnswer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username,
        string password, string email, string passwordQuestion,
        string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey,
        out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        //SOME CODE i DON'T WHANT YOU TO SEE :)
        string strStatus = "";
        string strUserid = "";

        status = (MembershipCreateStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(MembershipCreateStatus), strStatus, true);

        if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            int userid = 0;
            try
            {
                userid = Convert.ToInt32(strUserid);
            }
            catch
            {
                status = MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError;
            }

            MembershipUser mu = MU(username);
            return mu;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override bool DeleteUser(string username,
        bool deleteAllRelatedData)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection
        FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex,
        int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection
        FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex,
        int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        //GET PASS FROM SQL
        return "";
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        string UserName = (string)SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(SqlHelper.ConnString, CommandType.Text, "select .... WHERE UserID = " + providerUserKey.ToString());
        MembershipUser m = MU(UserName, userIsOnline);
        return m;
    }

    public override string ResetPassword(string username,
        string answer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    // Helper method
    private void ReadMembershipDataStore()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
        }
    }

    private MembershipUser MU(string UserName)
    {
        return MU(UserName, false);
    }

    private MembershipUser MU(string UserName, bool isOnline)
    {
        MembershipUser user = null;

        //SOME CODE

        return user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked in the code behind file?  This would be like login.aspx.cs.

Comment: i only have the `Page_Load` in the code behind which i have posted in my question...